# What is the maximum normal latency for internal gateway switch?

Tags: switch, ping, latency

I've been observing the ping latency to my server's internal gateway switch from my server machine. I noticed the ping spikes to as high as 500ms at times. Is this a possible indication that the switch is overload or this is perfectly normal?

Comment: From my workstation to the gateway (single switch) is <1ms. 500ms is probably an indication of a problem, but as TomTom stated, without knowing your topology we can only make a reasonable guess, based on our own response time.

Answer (score 2):

Define local gateway. WIthin a shorter lan (same room) with 1-2 switches nivolved unless the line is totally overloaded it should be low single digit ms - witha  strong push towards 0-1ms. I am jsut checking my VM I type that on to the firewall of my company (also a VM) via a physical router (i.e. traffic goes to router then from there to firewall) - definitely more than a simple switch - and I get 3, 1, 2, <1 ms.

500ms is RIDICULOUS - US is around 115ms from my place (europe) including a lot of routers in between. This is either some defective / overlaoded part or a really hard overload on the the line. It is extreme.

Comment: By local gateway, I meant internal switch/router

Comment: Which can still be in another building, you know. Anyhow, it sounds ridiculous high. Modem level.